# PowerShell Script fails to execute batch file on Remote server

Tags: powershell, batch-file, azure-devops, remote-server, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell script which works fine on windows server 2016 azure VM but fails to execute the same script from my build agent which is also window server 2016 OS azure VM. 
No errors get logged in PowerShell due to which i am not able to figure out what is the reasons?

Is there any Prerequisites that i need to validate or install on the server for executing this script?

Below is the script which execute batch file present on another another VM.

```
$Username = 'ABC'
$Password = 'XYZ'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ServerName" -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\CI\Demo_CI.bat'"
     Write-Host "done"
    }

} catch {
    Write-Host "error"
}
```

Comment: What's the error message do you receive? Basically it has the same prerequisites with `PowerShell on Target Machines task`, please see [`Prerequisites`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=vsts#prerequisites) for details.

Comment: I don't get any error message, it goes into catch section and displays error and i validated the prerequisites and The powershell is 5.1 and Windows management framework is also installed on my VM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are facing here is a Credential delegation issue, You can try enabling CredSSP in your build agent and the target "ServerName". To know more about credssp , see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/), therwise you will have to use psexec in CI.

Comment: I tried using CredSSP as well but still was not able to figure out the issue.